# DRF Register a sub viewset

Tags: django-rest-framework

I try to configure a viewset "behind" another one. Here is the code :

```py
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('places/nice', NicePlacesViewSet)
router.register('places/nice/current', CurrentNice remove last slash PlacesViewSet)
```

Both routes are available according to `/manage.py show_urls`, but if a do a GET on `places/nice/current`, I just get a 404 error.

And if a change the last line to remove last slash:

```py
router.register('places/nice_current', CurrentPlacesViewSet)
```

everything work perfectly and I can get current viewset informations.

Is there any limitations on nested viewsets like that ? Viewset should not be nested on the same path ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the ***order of the `register()` statements*** as

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('places/nice/current', CurrentPlacesViewSet)
router.register('places/nice', NicePlacesViewSet)
```

Comment: In fact, its that simple -_-
Thank you ! :)

Comment: My experience is quite different: the latest registration overrides the previous one, even though the subclass

- has a different name

- registers a different endpoint

- only partially redefines the original class.

In the case of a ModelViewSet, if the subclass only specialises the list method (e.g. to introduce a filter), its redefinition is nullified if the endpoint of the original class is registered later.

So, from my point of view, this is a malfunction.